# How to have sub components CSS class react on parent components CSS class?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

I am trying to get my head around a scenario with CSS components:
I have a react component that uses its own classes. This component has a little helper subcomponent that also has its own classes. Now: When a specific state in the main component is set and a specific class is applied then the helper component's css should react on that class.

For instance:

- Component A uses Component B to show something.
- Component A gets clicked on and react sets a "clicked"-class on that component
- Component B should then visually react on that class

In plain CSS (or similar) I would do this:

**Component A:**

```
.component {
  height: 10px;
}

.component.clicked {
  height: 5px;
}
```

**Component B**

```
.clicked {
  .subComponent {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

I know that there is a react way to do this. This kind of thing should be done with states and props which are being passed between the components so that this kind of situation gets avoided altogether. But I am currently refacturing a project that still has these issues and I don't really get how to do this properly with react-css-modules.

By the way: My current workaround uses :global but I'd really, really like to avoid this...

Comment: As you have mentioned, doing this using props and states is the proper way. And also read about Flux architecture. Flux giving an easy way to  handling more advance scenarios between parent and child components.

Comment: @ErangaKapukotuwa thank you for your answer. I have a very good understanding of react and flux, which is why I am not seeking knowledge about how to solve this issue the react way. I know how to do that. I am seeking knowledge about how to solve described situation in react-css-components. The scenario I described seems so mundane that I wonder why it is so difficult for me to find the right answer.

Comment: Seems I have misread your question and insult your knowledge. I extremely sorry about it.  Please publish the answer if you could able to find it. I also enthusiast for knowing that.

Answer (score 0):

**Component B:**

```
.clicked:onclick, .subComponent {
 // code ...
}
```

This should do it.
If not I'm just bad at css, or confused about your question.

Comment: Sorry, but this won't solve my issue. The problem is that with react-css-modules all CSS classes get rewritten to something random and component a and component b will thus deliver classes into the dom that are absolutely unique, even if they share the same classes in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

**Parent:**

---

```
var ComponentA = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            isClicked: false
        }
    },

    onClick: function() {
        this.setState({ isClicked: !this.state.isClicked });
    }),

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.state.isClicked ? "component clicked" : "component"}>
                <ComponentB isClicked={this.state.isClicked}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**Child:**

---

```
var ComponentB = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            isClicked: false
        }
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.isClicked ? "subComponent clicked" : "subComponent"}>
                I am the subComponent
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: My line "I know that there is a react way to do this" revers to exactly your proposal. While I am thankful for your effort I am looking for a solution that works solely with react-css-modules (excluding :local and :global). That is because all the logic is already there in the CSS and I currently do not have the time to refactor the whole project to utilize the react way.